# Socket Closed error when trying to reopen connection

Tags: java

I am making a program that requires the UI to update every time a client receives data from a server. To to this the socket and serversocket have to be closed and reopened every time. Although when the program tries to accept the new connection, here is my code and the error:

```
    public void startServer(){
    Thread serverstart = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
                try {       
                    serversocket = new ServerSocket(socket);

                    while(true){
                        skt = serversocket.accept();
                        close.setEnabled(true);
                        new Thread(new newClient(skt)).start();
                    }
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
        }
    };serverstart.start();
}
static class newClient implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket;
    static PrintStream output;
    public newClient(Socket skt){
        this.socket = skt;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
        output = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

    public void sendData(){                 
        tallydata = Integer.toString(preview) + " " + Integer.toString(program);        
                System.out.println(tallydata);
                newClient.output.print(tallydata);

        try{
                skt.close();
                serversocket.close();
            } catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            startServer();                  
    }
```

The socket is closed at the end of the sendData() method and the startServer() method is called to restart the connection again after that. Here is the error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
    at TallySystem.servergui$1.run(servergui.java:201)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you closing and reopening the server anyway? Just start it once and leave it alone. Thats how it should be used.

Anyway, as per the [ServerSocket documentation](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#close%28%29):

> public void close()
>
> Closes this socket. Any thread currently blocked in accept() will throw a SocketException.

Thats precisely your problem. You are closing the ServerSocket while its busy awaiting connections.